# Display shortest way on mapkit without having the route divided in two different segment

Tags: objective-c, ipad, mapkit

I'm currently developing an iPad application that integrates MapKit. But I have a small issue. I display lines between two points on my map but when these points are one at the very west of the map and an other one at the very east of it, for instance, I would like to draw the shortest line between then. In other words, I would like to center my map between these two points (but not in the usual way because If I do so I have to draw a line from the left one that goes left to the left border of the map, then continues from the right border to the right marker... so on the opposite point of the map) and then draw the shortest route that is know in the middle of my view. 
I've thought of two ideas that could help me... 
  - Change the map background and have a map centered on a different place of the planet,
  - Instead of a map as background, have 2 maps side to side and switch to the right one according to what I need to display,

But I couldn't find anything about it... Do you know if these solutions would be possible and how ? If not, would you have an other idea about how to do what I'm trying to do ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it might help others people...
I didn't found any way to modify the background map in my map view and I have been forced to display some routes in two parts. Indeed, it seems impossible to do differently so far with the mapKit iOS library. We can only wait for improvements ;) !